# extra activity created/onCreate() called when pausing app then resuming from lockscreen

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle, oncreate

when clicking the home button which exits my app and also calls onPause(), 
Then I re-open my app from a lock screen notification, onCreate() gets called even though the activity was never destroyed initially. which leads to the user having to press the back key 2+ times to exit the app and destroy all the activities.
the user should only have to press the back key once to exit the app.
this only happens when I exit the app using the home button.
 [heres a video demo of the bug](https://vid.me/nKMK)

```
 @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onResume", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    buttonToggleDetect.setBackground(ui.uiToggle(getApplicationContext(), detectEnabled));


    // ACTIVITY RECOGNITION BELOW
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver, new IntentFilter(Constants.STRING_ACTION));


    // ACTIVITY RECOGNITION ABOVE ^^

    mTracker.setScreenName("Image~" + name);
    mTracker.send(new HitBuilders.ScreenViewBuilder().build());
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"onPause",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver);
    super.onPause();
}


@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onStart", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    // ACTIVITY RECOGNITION BELOW
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();

    // ACTIVITY RECOGNITION ABOVE ^^

    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    detectEnabled = preferences.getBoolean("mode", false);


    buttonToggleDetect.setBackground(ui.uiToggle(getApplicationContext(), detectEnabled));

}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"onStop",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    // ACTIVITY RECOGNITION BELOW
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
    }

    // ACTIVITY RECOGNITION ABOVE ^^



}

public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"onDestroy",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

} //onDestroy End
```

cant figure out how to fix it.
any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Post your code please

Comment: added in the code there

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by adding 
`android:noHistory="true">`

to the manifest in the activity tag.